# Determining the Probability Distrubitive Function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A coffee chain claims that you have a 1 in 9 chance of winning a prize on their “roll up the edge” promotion, where you roll up the edge of your paper cup to see if you win. If so, what is the probability you have no winners in a one week period where you bought 15 cups of coffee?

Part (b):

Over the last week of a month long promotion you and your friends bought 60 cups of coffee, but there was only 1 winner. Find the probability that there would be this few (i.e. 1 or 0) winners. What might you conclude?

I'm not sure which technique to use, or how to begin this.  Any help will be great thanks!

Comment: added part b if anyone can help thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the binomial distribution:

Experiment: Randomly sample 9 Coffee Cups

Random Variable: # of Winners

Possible Values: 0     1     2     3     ...     8     9

Dichotomous Outcomes: Success = Winner, Failure = Not Winner

Constant Probability: P(Winner) = 0.1111

Independence? P(Winner|Any previous Outcomes) = P(Winner) = 0.1111

Since random variable is the number of success, this is a binomial experiment with n= 9 and p = 0.1111.

Now, use binomial tables or

$P(X=0) = \dfrac{9!}{0!(9-0)!} (0.1111)^0(1−0.111)^{9−0} $ = about 0.17

as in Mark Fischler. Generalize for the second part, or use normal approximation to the binomial.

Comment: I still keep getting the wrong answer for the second part.

can you give me a good starting point?

Comment: Use general formula for binomial probability:

Comment: $P(X=x) = \dfrac{n!}{x!(n-x)!} (0.1111)^x(1−0.111)^{n−x} $

Comment: First use n=60 and x=0, then use n=60 and x=1; add the results.

Comment: Got it thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that to have no winners you need 15 successes on independent variables of "this one didn't win" -- each of which has probability $1-1/9$.

The probability of no winners is 
$$
\left( \frac{8}{9} \right)^{15}
$$
which is about 17%.

Comment: Do you happen to know which method/technique is being used here? Would it be the geometric?